# Unable to reference a target web app project for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, owin-middleware

I created a .NET Core web app in VS2015 using the empty web app template. It targets the full framework 4.6.1. It is for a middleware which I am using across a number of other web apps. I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware#writing-middleware), and the middleware works when I integrate it with another web app.

Now I want to write some unit tests for it, so I created a unit test project (using the Test Project template) that is targetting the same framework. Then I referenced the project that has the middleware class I want to unit test. But when I try to use the middleware class in my unit test method, VS would complain and say it could not find it, even if I type with fully qualified namespace. In fact, Intellisense is not bringing up any class in the target project. And if I try to build the unit test project, it would return an error: `The type or namespace name 'xxxxMiddleware' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. And when I go into my test unit's **References** and double-click the project that is the target of my unit test, VS pops the message `The project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built. Please ensure that the project is available and built.`

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

If I reference the `.exe` for my target project, it manages to resolve my middleware class. Very odd! I may have to do that workaround for now until I get a better answer.

**UPDATE 2**

I spoke too soon. Adding the `.exe` lets me compile my unit test project. But if I run the test, I get an error saying `System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly '{assembly for the target of my test}' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`. What a nightmare.

Comment: build your main project first and then try to add a reference to it

Comment: @greenshade, I'm not sure what you mean but I already built the project I wanted to target for unit testing. I could actually reference it from other web apps where I want to use it.

Comment: Does .NET framework version match in both projects?

Comment: One is a .NET Core web app that targets full framework 4.6.1. The unit test project also targets 4.6.1